# Magento 2 extension not working

Tags: magento2, extensions, multistore

I have installed a multistore extension (https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-currency-auto-switcher.html)

but it is not working in the frontend, the stores and currency are not switching automatically, I have to change them manually then they are working.

I have run these commands::
uploaded unzip folders in Magento respective subfolders

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

I have also done all the configurations and enabled the extension also.

After running these commands the design of the site gets disturbed and all the CSS and JS files are not loaded OR not found, so the first issue is how to run the css and js files and another issue is that if they run then stores and currencies are not auto-switched.

What may be the issue?

Comment: Hi, try to delete the **pub/static/frontend**, the **generated/metadata** and **generated/code**, **var/cache**, **var/page_cache**, and re-run your commands.